# Проблема при загрузке файла

Tags: файлы, php

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/phptesting/quest_day2/upload.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="5555555">
Выберите файл: <input name="userfile" type="file">
<input type="submit" value="Upload">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

upload.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charse="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?
    echo "ну-с, попробуем залить <br>";
    $url = '/var/www/phptesting/quest_day2/upload';
    $error = $_FILES['userfile']['error'];
    echo "$error<br>";
    $file_name = $_FILES['userfile']['name']; //файл
    $ext = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);  //расширение
    $size_file = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];  // размер
    echo filesize($file_name);
    echo "size_file = $size_file <br> ext = $ext <br>";

    if ($ext == "gif"){
        printf("Ошибка: недопустимое разрешение!<br>");
    }
    else{
        printf("Начало загрузки файла...<br>");
        if($FILES["userfile"]["size"] != 0 && $FILES['userfile']['size'] <= 5000000){
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], 
               $url."/".basename($_FILES['userfile']['name'])))
            {
                echo "<br>Файл успешно загружен.<br>";
            }
        }

        else {

            printf("Ошибка: файл пустой либо превыен максимальный размер.(5 мб)<br>");
        }

    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Вывод:

```
ну-с, попробуем залить 
2
size_file = 0 
ext = sh 
Начало загрузки файла...
Ошибка: файл пустой либо превыен максимальный размер.(5 мб)
```

Как решить эту проблему? не определяет размер файла.. `$_FILES['userfile']['error'] == 2` даже когда удаляю `<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="5555555">`. Помогите начинающему/..

Answer (score 1):

В коде проверки размера файла массив **$_FILES** записан как **$FILES** т.е. отсутствует знак нижнего подчёркивая, отсюда и нулевой размер. Удаление инпута с MAX_FILE_SIZE вообще тут не причём.